# Find first occurence of each of these patterns, with grep

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, find

This:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log |grep -m 1 123.123.123.123
```

gives me the first occurence of the IP 123.123.123.123.

But how to get the 1st occurence of IP1 **and** the 1st occurence of IP2 **and** the 1st occurence of IP3 **and** ... ?

This obviously doesn't work but it gives the idea:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log |grep -m 1 123.123.123.123 AND 124.124.124.124 AND 125.125.125.125
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use awk to do this (assuming the ip is the first column):

```
awk '!seen[$1]++ && $1 ~ /123.123.123.123|124.124.124.124|125.125.125.125/' /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `grep '123.123.123.123'` does not give you the first occurrence of the `123.123.123.123` *IP*, but of the `123.123.123.123` pattern which does match on `123.123.123.123` but also on `1234123-123e123` as `.` is the regular expression operator that matches any single character.

The `123\.123\.123\.123` would match on `123.123.123.123` only but note that so would `23\.123\.123\.1`. See also the `-F` option of `grep` for fixed-string matching.

Here, I'd do:

```
awk '
  !ips_seen {ip[$0]; n++; next}
  {
    found = 0
    for (i in ip)
      if (index($0, i)) {
        found = 1
        delete ip[i]
        n--
      }
  }
  found
  !n {exit}' ips.txt ips_seen=1 input.txt
```

Where `ips.txt` contains the list of IP addresses, one per line.

Note that we take care that if one line contains more than one of the IPs, it's still printed only once.

By using `index()` which just looks for substrings, we take care of the first problem above of `.` matching any character, but not of the second one.